# App images in high resolution screen

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app,I decide to only suport high resolution screen(iphone4 and later),so there is some question:

1. does it necessary to provider high resolution screen image(the @2x image)? if not, how should I name the image, a.png or a@2x.png?
2. if  I only provider high resolution screen image(the @2x image), say a image named a@2x.png, should I use it like this `'[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"];'` or like this `[UIImage imageNamed:@"a@2x"]`? when in storyboard, should I use a.png or a@2x.png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for questions:

-> does it necessary to provider high resolution screen image(the @2x image)? if not, how should I name the image, a.png or a@2x.png?

**Sol: Yes, you have to provide high resolution screen image just double the original image with a name orignalimage@2x.png. Suppose a image name is a.png(20x20pixels), for high resolution you have to give a name a@2x.png(40x40pixels).**

-> if I only provider high resolution screen image(the @2x image), say a image named a@2x.png, should I use it like this '[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"];' or like this [UIImage imageNamed:@"a@2x"]? when in storyboard, should I use a.png or a@2x.png?

**Sol: You have to give `[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];`.**

Hope this solves your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,this bother me hours!

Answer (score 2):

This is the official documentation of this topic:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html

To make it simple:

1. create your high resolution image and name it like *filename@2x.png*
2. add those images to your project
3. reference from the app by using *[UIImage imageNamed:@"filename"]*

Pls note that from iOS4 you can ommit the file name extension.

That's all, hope you can manage in your app. Comment if you have questions!

Comment: Thanks for your answer,that's helpful.But I still have one question:when I use a UIImageView in storyboard display an image,should I use _filename_.png or _filename@2x_.png for this

Comment: If you use and you drop one UIImageView onto your view canvas (or Image View as you can read on the Object Library) you will select the Image attribute using the combobox of Attributes Inspector. Only those images are listed which are added to your project. So when you visually edit your view you will see a filename.png in the Attributes Inspector. I think and my experience is that if you manage UIImageView programatically, you can either use filename.png or filename. Historically I always use filename.png... Hope it is an answer to your question.. ;)

Comment: Storyboard, if I understand well, is for designing the flow of the screens, you add actually the image view to your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, all High resolution images have to be named with the @2x suffix. In your code you use the classic name, without the @2x suffix, if your app is running on retina screen it's your high resolution pictures which will be used.

Answer (score 0):

1 does it necessary to provider high resolution screen image(the @2x image)? if not, how should I name the image, a.png or a@2x.png?

**Reply:- If you want to app for iPhone4 or later ,No need without retina image, but image name must @2x.png. if you are use .png image you found the image is blurred in iPhone 4 Simulator.**

2) if I only provider high resolution screen image(the @2x image), say a image named a@2x.png, should I use it like this '[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"];' or like this [UIImage imageNamed:@"a@2x"]? when in storyboard, should I use a.png or a@2x.png?

**Reply:- **you are only use high resolution screen image high resolution screen image ,depend on image resolution**

Comment: I'm not agree with that, he do not have to use [UIImage imageNamed:@"a@2x"] but [UIImage imageNamed:@"a"], it's not to him to manage image resolution, it depends of device resolution and it has to be transparent inside the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,that is helpful,and I agree with @shawn,we should let the device manage image resolution.